# taskscheduleR: cannot find the function "as"

Tags: r, rscript, r-taskscheduler

I am trying to use the taskscheduleR add-in in RStudio to run a script weekly. Every time I get the same error:

> cannot find the function "as".

```
Quitting from lines 25-83 (association_analysis.Rmd)
Fehler in as(dataToTrans, "transactions") :
konnte Funktion "as" nicht finden
Ruft auf: render ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

The part of R script, where the error is throwing:

```
library('arules')
#create transactions
transactions <- as(dataToTrans, "transactions")
inspect(head(transactions))
```

It works when I run the script in RStudio, but not with taskscheduleR. Any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: Try Explicitly loading the methods package in your script

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
library(methods)
```

to the .Rmd, since `as` is a function from this package.